# Feynman parametrization with three denominators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, propagator

I'm triyng compute some integral loops for my thesis and I need use Feynman's parametrization with three denominators, I've used the general formula like:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{A_1A_2...A_n}=(n-1)!\int_0^1dx_1\int_0^1dx_2...\int_0^1dx_n\delta\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)\frac{1}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_kx_k\right)^n}
\end{equation}
For two denominators there is no problem, for example $n=2$, then the formula gives
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{A_1A_2}=\int_0^1dx_1\int_0^1dx_2\delta(1-x_1-x_2)\frac{1}{\left(A_1x_1+A_2x_2\right)^2}
\end{equation}
we remember the parity of Dirac Delta, then
\begin{equation}
    \delta(1-x_1-x_2)=\delta\left(x_2-(1-x_1)\right)
\end{equation}
now the integral can be computing easily
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{A_1A_2}=\int_0^1dx_1\frac{1}{\left(A_1x_1+A_2(1-x_1)\right)^2}.
\end{equation}
I know that result is correct because when computing the second integration gives $1/A_1A_2$. The problem arises when I try compute for three denominators, for example setting $n=3$, then the formula gives:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{A_1A_2A_3}=2\int_0^1dx_1\int_0^1dx_2\int_0^1dx_3\delta(1-x_1-x_2-x_3)\frac{1}{\left(A_1x_1+A_2x_2+A_3x_3\right)^3}
\end{equation}

again, we can use the parity of Dirac Delta, then
\begin{equation}
    \delta(1-x_1-x_2-x_3)=\delta(x_3-(1-x_1-x_2))
\end{equation}
now the integration can be computing easily like
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{A_1A_2A_3}=2\int_0^1\frac{dx_1dx_2}{\left(A_1x_1+A_2x_2+A_3(1-x_1-x_2)\right)^3}
\end{equation}
Up to this point I think I've used the formula correctly but I've found a parametrization like:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{A_1A_2A_3}=2\int_0^1\frac{dx_1dx_2x_1}{\left(A_1x_1x_2+A_2x_1(1-x_2)+A_3(1-x_1)\right)^3}
\end{equation}
I need the last equation to continue but I don't know how. Tell me if I have not used the formula correctly.

A web site explain about the limits but I can't understand: [https://kodu.ut.ee/~kkannike/english/science/physics/notes/feynman_param.html](https://kodu.ut.ee/%7Ekkannike/english/science/physics/notes/feynman_param.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484621/2451